# Find out if a photo is monochrome/sepia from a big group of photos

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing, selection

I'm trying to design an algorithm for selecting photos which are monochrome (the one photographers call "black & white") and have a single color toning such as sepia. (think as you've applied a solid color filter to a monochrome image) If I was after just monochrome only, all I need is to check the saturation which is easy (and I'm currently doing it), but it is unsuccessful at finding solid-color-toned monochrome photos. What could be an approach for that one?

Comment: Idea: compute the cross-correlation coefficients between each pair of color channels. Declare the image to be monochrome if they are all sufficiently close to 1. (Defining "sufficiently close" will require some experimentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an image is monochrome, either black and white or sepia, the colors corresponding to each lightness level should be nearly identical. Convert the image colorspace to one which contains a Luminance (Y) or Lightness component, such as YCbCr or HSL, and for each Y/L value look at the variance in the other two channels. If the values cluster together, you have a monochrome image.

Comment: starting from the wikipedia article about RGB and HSL, i've found out that *chroma* is what I want. implemented it and it works really well..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could look at the distribution/pattern of values within the R,G & B histograms, if you use something like photoshop to visualize the histogram of a monochromatic image you will see that the distribution of the "pattern" of the histogram is similar across all three channels (would need to be normalized), whereas the distribution for each channel on a full color image is (typically) quite different. For the most part that is... there are situations where a full-color image may still give off a monochromatic flavor like a rainbow gradient in photoshop - but this is contrived and it's likely that this wouldn't occur frequently in "natural" photography.

Comment: yeah, it's very unlikely to have near-equal histogram per channel for a "really colorful" photo. so that method SHOULD work in theory, i'll be coding that and see how it turns out..

Answer (score 1):

If your image is monochrome, the saturation of all the pixels will all be approximately 0. If your image is toned (like sepia colored), all of the pixels will have approximately the same hue.